# YII simple form validation ( not a CActiveForm or CHtml form)

Tags: forms, validation, yii

Is it possible to build and validate a simple html form (not a CActiveForm or CHtml widget form) with yii validate() method.If yes, please give suitable and simple example.I can't find anything about this on web,
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think yes, try to sent it like Model[field] with the POST method. And disable csrf token.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use validation without help of CActiveForm and Chtml

use in your html tag name like Model[attribute]

```
      <input type="text" name="User[full_name]">
```

in your controller function disabled _csrf token

```
        function actionSave() {
             $this->enableCsrfValidation = false;
              <--here your code
               -->

         }
```